# Print a list in c++

Tags: c++, list

I have the following structure:

```
struct People{
    string name;    
    string surname; 
    string number;  
};
```

How can i print all people in list? I created a few people in main and tried to print them, but i get error.

```
    int main(int argn, char** args) {

        list<People> test_list;

        People first;
        first.name= "Name1";
        first.surname= "Surname1";
        first.number= "E1234567";
        test_list.push_back(first);

        People second;
        second.name= "Name2";
        second.surname= "Surname2";
        second.number= "E2345678";
        test_list.push_back(second);

        People third;
        third.name= "Name3";
        third.surname= "Surname3";
        third.number= "E3456789";
        test_list.push_back(third);

        list<People>::iterator i;
            for( i = test_list.begin(); i != test_list.end(); ++i)
                cout << *i << " ";
            cout << endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

Does anybody know the propper way to print a list?

Comment: Why does it matter if the people are stored in a list?

Comment: My crystal ball was broken recently. Can you specify the exact error in your question?

Comment: what should `cout << *i << " ":` do in your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to print the details:

```
cout << i->name << " "<< i->surname << " "<< i->number << " ";
```

Answer (score 2):

You should define `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&,const People&)`, which should simply print the data inside your People instance.

Answer (score -1):

I assume that, you are trying to print the variable of structure.Inside the for loop, you have specified the pointer, which is pointing to each element of list. But you haven't specified the element inside the structure. So, for that,

```
count<<(*i).name<<endl; // for printing name
```

Alternatively, you can also use `->` like this

```
count<<i->name; // for printing name.
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: `*(i->name)` this is wrong it's `(*i).name` or `i->name`